# Alternating Ranked Query in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, ranking

Imagine a Table athletes. It has a name, a high jump score and a long jump score.

```
CREATE TABLE athletes (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    high_jump_score DECIMAL,
    long_jump_score DECIMAL
);

    
    
INSERT INTO athletes (name, high_jump_score, long_jump_score) VALUES
    ('Canga Roo', 2, 8),
    ('Bob Johnson', 1.90, 7.5),
    ('John Doe', 1.85, 7.2),
    ('Jane Smith', 1.75, 6.8),
    ('Alice Brown', 1.76, 6.7);
```

Now I would like to create a query that alternately lists the highest hi-jumper, followed by the highest long jumper (unless they are the same person, in which case second best long jumper), followed by the second highest hi-jumper and so on. Every athlete appears once, at their respective highest rank.

Think of it like this. You have a list of the athletes in front of you, with their scores and a blank sheet of paper. You select the best hi jumper from the list and write him first on the paper, then cross him of the list. Now you select the next best long jumper and then cross him of the list. Now you select the next best hi jumper and cross him off. You do that until all athletes are crossed out.

What makes this tricky is avoiding doubles. The correct solution would be:

```
Canga Roo; 1st Hi-Jump
Bob Johnson; 1st Long-Jump
John Doe; 2nd Hi-Jump
Alice Brown; 2nd Long-Jump
Jame Smit; 3rd Hi-jump
```

I tried rank ordering all of them first by Hi-Jump, then Long-Jump, then selecting the respective highest rank (f-rank) between Hi-Rank and Long-Rank, assigning a group based on which is higher and finally ordering by f-rank first, group second:

```
WITH RankedAthletes AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        high_jump_score,
        long_jump_score,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY high_jump_score DESC) AS hi_rank,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY long_jump_score DESC) AS long_rank
    FROM athletes
)
, FinalRanking AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        hi_rank,
        long_rank,
        LEAST(hi_rank,long_rank) as f_rank,
     ( CASE
        WHEN hi_rank < long_rank THEN 'Hi-Jump'
        ELSE 'Long-Jump'
    END ) AS "group"
    FROM RankedAthletes
)
SELECT
    name,
    hi_rank,
    long_rank,
    f_rank,
    "group",
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "group" ORDER BY f_rank) final_rank 
FROM FinalRanking
ORDER BY final_rank, "group";
```

Unfortunetly, that ends with Alice Brown being on top, since she's the only on who's hi-jump rank is not identical to her long-jump rank and so she's the only one in group 0 and so she's on top.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Is there a way to solve this so that it correctly assigns people to the groups?

**EDIT:**

Second Example to show the Problem better:

```
INSERT INTO athletes (name, high_jump_score, long_jump_score) VALUES
    ('Canga Roo', 10, 10),
    ('Bob Johnson', 1, 5),
    ('John Doe', 2, 4),
    ('Jane Smith', 3, 3),
    ('Alice Brown', 4, 2);
```

Desired Result

```
Canga Roo, 1st Hi Jump
Bob Johnson, 1st Long Jump
Alice Brown, 2nd Hi Jump
John Doe, 2nd Long Jump
Jane Smith, 1st Hi Jump
```

Comment: I don't see Alice on top: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GA-Vcj7E). I think you could've changed something in the sample data set you showed, or the one you tested.

Comment: yep, sorry about that

Comment: Your spec says nothing about listed people being distinct unless immediately adjacent: if I treat your criteria verbatim, a person who scores first as a high jumper and last as a long jumper, should be listed twice: once on top, once on the bottom. Is that desired behaviour, or should everyone appear at most once?

Comment: I'll fix that. They are only supposed to appear once, at the highest position they can be (ie if your rank as a high jumper is higher than that as a long jumper, your high jumper rank counts).

Answer (score 1):

You can list them all twice with [`union all`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION) making their long/high jump rank end up in the same column that you then order by and decide which jump comes first using adding a `boolean` saying which is which. [`lead()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) can tell you if the previously listed name is the same as the current one. [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) can make sure everyone's listed at most once, at their highest position, at which point you no longer need comparing to `lead()`. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/buZ_Sl8s)

```sql
with ranked1 as (
    select
        name,
        high_jump_score,
        long_jump_score,
        row_number() over (order by long_jump_score desc) as rank1,
        true as is_long_jump_rank
    from athletes
    union all
    select
        name,
        high_jump_score,
        long_jump_score,
        row_number() over (order by high_jump_score desc) as rank1,
        false as is_long_jump_rank
    from athletes )
,ranked2 as (
    select distinct on (name) *,
           row_number()over (order by rank1, is_long_jump_rank) as rank2
    from ranked1 
    order by name,rank2)
select name,
       high_jump_score,
       long_jump_score,
       row_number()over(order by rank2) as final_rank 
from ranked2
order by final_rank;
```

| name | high_jump_score | long_jump_score | final_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Canga Roo | 2 | 8 | 1 |
| Bob Johnson | 1.90 | 7.5 | 2 |
| John Doe | 1.85 | 7.2 | 3 |
| Alice Brown | 1.76 | 6.7 | 4 |
| Jane Smith | 1.75 | 6.8 | 5 |

Comment: on thing I don't understand, shouldnt is_long_jump_rank alternate between rows? Since you should always be selecting the next highest in alternating categories?

Comment: It does because when `union all` glues everything together, it's then ordered by the `rank1` column, and then the `is_long_jump_rank` after that, which effectively reorders them in a way that results in that value alternating row-to-row. If you scroll down the demo, there's a cell saying `--debug` on top and its result shows that happening.

Comment: why do you need to both check for is_different_from_previous and do a distinct? Wouldn't the distinct be enough?

Comment: Good point, that was a leftover from when I assumed you don't necessarily want unique names, as long as adjacent rows hold distinct names. With the `distinct on` in place, `lead()` comparison is redundant. I've added an update

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work quite how I want. I've added a second example where your code doesn't produce the desired result. It really needs to alternate on every row between highest hi jumper and long jumper.